# Groups for which indecomposable representation implies irreducible

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

(Let's say we work over $\mathbb{C}$.)

It is well-known that if $\rho: G \to \operatorname{GL}(V)$ is a representation of a finite group $G$, then it is irreducible iff it is indecomposable. This is usually done by the averaging trick, which produces a non-degenerate bilinear form on $V$ fixed by $G$. It is also well-known, that the same property holds for **continuous** representations of compact topological group, by a similar argument.

My question is: let $G$ be a group which does not have reducible but indecomposable representations. Does it necessarily mean that $G$ is finite?

My remark about compact groups is not contradictory here, as we ignore the topological structure of $G$ (if there is any), so we can construct some wild representations. For instance, if $G$ is the unit circle group $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$, we can find some irrational element $a$, and a subgroup $H$ such that $G = \mathbb{Q}a \oplus H$. Then representation given by

$$ qa+h \mapsto \begin{pmatrix} 1&q \newline 0&1 \end{pmatrix} $$
(for $q$ rational, $h \in H$) is indecomposable, but reducible.

Comment: I presume you want $G$ to already be a linear group? Because otherwise one may produce lots of counterexamples.

Comment: Oh, yes, making that assumption sounds reasonable

Comment: Can you clarify all the restrictions? Any finite dimensional complex representation of $G=\Bbb{Q/Z}$ is isomorphic to a direct sum of 1-dimensional representations.

Comment: Well, I think it is the answer to my question, then.